# css3 3d flipping tile transform animation

Tags: css, 3d, transform, rotatetransform

I want to be able to have a smooth 3d rotating effect from from small to big.

I can't understand why the Tiles are starting big and not small. so it should be a rotating
effect until they all position absolutely.

please have a look the demo

http://codepen.io/davide77/pen/CxiDa

```
@keyframes scale {

  0% {transform: rotateY(360deg) scale(0);}
  50% { transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(1);}
 100% { transform: rotateY(360deg) scale(1);}
}
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: http://codepen.io/nbatothemax/pen/HmIgA?

Comment: nearly there! but not yet! they should be coming from small to big. looks like is loading with them and then starts the animation if it makes sense?

Comment: Aren't they? What do you want to happen, your question is unclear..